# Save to another partition

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu with two partitions, one is for the systems and the other is for all the datas. But as I installed programs it goes to the systems partition and makes the disk full. Is it possible to install the programs to my other partitions since it has bigger memory?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you run `sudo blkid`

Comment: it gave me this 'code' /dev/sda1: UUID="ac3d9220-b04d-41bc-b223-cf7997825f02" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="92b26efc-9ab8-4258-a451-a4848d79fdae" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="a8eb9395-9113-4154-9354-a59764bd529f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="E579-588C" TYPE="vfat" 'code'

Comment: Ok, it's the `UUID="a8eb9395-9113-4154-9354-a59764bd529f" TYPE="ext4" /dev/sda4` you are going to target.

Comment: The problem is an application in Ubuntu is spread out all over the filesystem.

It will put the bulk of it's stuff in /usr (binaries and libraries), some stuff in /etc (configuration), some stuff in /var (transient files, logs), etc.

My best suggestion is to make root partition bigger. 10 Gb or a bit more for root.

Comment: my root partition is already 10 gb. my total harddisk is 500, and i made 10 for the systems and the rest for swap and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this guide:  [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Ask me for help and guidance if you are unsure during the task.

Comment: this guide will make ubuntu put installed programs to the other partition right?? the fstab thing kinda scared me though, i thought it's going to format my system partition. am i getting it right?

Comment: No. This guide will split your installation into a root (`/`) partition that holds your system data and a `/home` partition that holds user data. This is the traditional way to do such things in Linux. It's awkward in Linux to install programs to arbitrary locations, and if you set things up correctly in the first place, it's seldom desirable to want to do so.

Comment: but when I install applications and games from ubuntu software center it goes to my / partition, i want it to go to my /home partition